# Given min-value, max-value and mean, can I elegantly generate data to fit a bell curve?

Tags: javascript, math, statistics

Let's say I have an array of objects.

I have 3 values associated with this array: min-height, max-height and average-height.

I want to assign a height to each object so that:

- No object's height is less than min-height
- No object's height is greater than max-height
- The mean of all objects' heights is average-height.

Essentially I am looking to generate a height distribution like this:

[image]

The heights have to be pseudo-random - that is to say, I want to be able to get a height for each object by feeding the result of a random number generator into a function and getting the height returned.

My solution at the moment is to split my range of acceptable heights (all between min-height and max-height) into a series of bins and assign a probability to each bin. Once a bin is selected, I choose a height from within that range at random.

This is not an ideal solution as it is inelegant, clunky, and produces a stepped curve as opposed to a smooth one.

[image]

Here is my current code for producing the bins:

```
var min_height = 10
var max_height = 100
var avg_height = 30

var scale = SCALE ()
    .map_from([min_height, avg_height, max_height])
    .map_to([-Math.PI, 0, Math.PI])

var range = max_height - min_height;

var num_of_bins = 10
var bin_size = range/num_of_bins;

var bins = []
var sum_of_probability = 0

while (bins.length < num_of_bins) {
    var bin = {};
    bin.min = min_height + (bins.length*bin_size);
    bin.max = bin.min + bin_size;
    bin.mid = bin.min + (bin_size/2);

    bin.probability = Math.cos(scale(bin.mid))+1
    sum_of_probability += bin.probability;

    bins.push(bin)
}

var i;
var l = bins.length;
for (i=0; i<l; i++) {
    bins[i].probability /= sum_of_probability

    if (bins[i-1]) {
        bins[i].cumulative_probability = bins[i-1].cumulative_probability + bins[i].probability;
    }
    else {
        bins[i].cumulative_probability = bins[i].probability;
    }
}
```

Essentially I would love to be able to generate pseudo-random data to roughly fit a curve in an elegant way, and I am not sure if this is possible in javascript. Let me know if you think this is do-able.

Comment: d3.js may be helpful

Comment: Hi Hemant! In this situation I actually am not able to use d3.js, however I would be interested to know how to do it with so I could possibly make use of some of the same functionality.

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like a homework problem. JavaScript, or any programming language, doesn't really play into it much, as this is just a basic math problem which is easily represented in any language. Can you share your "inelegant, clunky" solution so we know what you've tried so far?

Comment: How did you get the probabilities for the bins? You seem to have more information than just the 3 numbers you mention (which underdetermine the problem since there are infinitely many continuous probability distributions with a given min, mean, and max). Depending on what you are trying to do, you might want to read up on the beta distribution which gives a reasonable way to get such distributions (after a suitable linear transformation from `(0,1)` to `(min,max)`).

Comment: You might also want to look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution

Comment: @samanime I've just edited my question to include my current code to show how I generate and assign probabilities to bins. I use a function SCALE - assume this works similarly to d3.js's scaleLinear function. This code is non-ideal in several ways.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks for the link. I have now edited my question to include the current code I use for selecting height 'bins' and assigning a probability to them. I suppose I should give some context - this code is generating the heights of visual svg elements - trees in a forest. I want there to be variance in height within bounds I define (hence min, max and avg heights). These are the 3 values I want the user to be able to input. If I do need additional information (and my problem here is that I don't know if I do!) I imagine I would store that in an external settings file.

Answer (score 2):

I borrowed the Gaussian "class" from here: [html5 draw gaussian function using bezierCurveTo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356343/html5-draw-gaussian-function-using-beziercurveto).

The stuff that's really relevant to you is the `getPoints()` function. Basically, given a min, max and average height, `getPoints()` will return an array with a smooth gaussian curve of values. You can then take those points and scale them over whatever range you would need (just multiply them).

The `numSteps` value of `generateValues` (which `getPoints` has hard-coded to 1000) controls how many values you get back, giving you a better "resolution". If you did something like 10, you'd have the values for something like your bar graph. Given 1000 gives a nice smooth curve.

Hope this helps.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 200;

var Gaussian = function(mean, std) {
  this.mean = mean;
  this.std = std;
  this.a = 1/Math.sqrt(2*Math.PI);
};

Gaussian.prototype = {
  addStd: function(v) {
    this.std += v;
  },

  get: function(x) {
    var f = this.a / this.std;
    var p = -1/2;
    var c = (x-this.mean)/this.std;
    c *= c;
    p *= c;
    return f * Math.pow(Math.E, p);
  },

  generateValues: function(start, end, numSteps = 100) {
    var LUT = [];
    var step = (Math.abs(start)+Math.abs(end)) / numSteps;
    for(var i=start; i<end; i+=step) {
      LUT.push(this.get(i));
    }
    return LUT;
  }
};

const getPoints = () => {
  const minHeight = 0;
  const maxHeight = 200;
  const averageHeight = 50;

  const start = -10;
  const end = 10;
  const mean = averageHeight / (maxHeight - minHeight) * (end - start) + start;
  const std = 1;
  
  const g = new Gaussian(mean, std);
  return g.generateValues(start, end, 1000);
}

const draw = () => {
  const points = getPoints();

  // x-axis
  ctx.moveTo(0, canvas.height - 20);
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height - 20);
  
  // y-axis
  ctx.moveTo(canvas.width / 2, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height);
  
  ctx.moveTo(0, canvas.height - 20);
  console.log(points);
  for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(i * (canvas.width / points.length),      
      canvas.height - points[i] * canvas.height - 20);
  }
  
  ctx.stroke();
};

draw();
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

canvas {
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```